# Cause for EFI Signature Change on PopOS Linux

Tags: linux, uefi, secure-boot

I have a system with popos 21.10 installed. I had added the `vmlinuz.efi` signature to the secure boot list. Today I tried to boot the system after a week idle and it gave me an error saying the signature is invalid. I'm trying to figure out why this happened. I know malware is a possible reason, but given how little use the system has seen I doubt this is the case.

I catted out `/var/log/apt/history.log` and I spotted in the recent update I ran:

```
linux-image-5.15.11-76051511-generic:amd64
linux-headers-5.15.11-76051511-generic:amd64
linux-modules-5.15.11-76051511-generic:amd64
...
linux-headers-generic:amd64
linux-image-generic:amd64
```

The list goes on, it clearly updated the kernel. Is this the cause of the `vmlinuz.efi` change? I'm not familiar with the lower level details on how EFI secure boot works. If this is the cause of the change is there an list of valid signatures I check against?

Comment: From what I can gather, Pop_OS is not signed at all. So whatever you set up before, you did manually.

Comment: So is the .efi file just updated every time the kernel files get updated?

Comment: Sure. It _is_ the kernel image.